# PerformancePoint - How do I select from all members in a dimension based on a list when making a KPI?

Tags: 2010, performancepoint

I have set up a SharePoint task list that my team is using to track regular deliverables. Based on this, I have created a KPI in PerformancePoint that uses the task list as a data source. I have also defined all of my fields in my data source correctly, in terms of dimensions, time dimensions and measures.

However, when I am creating an Actual or Target measure as part of my KPI, I am finding that I am unable to select all of the members of my task list's Status column. The column is defined with multiple values in a dropdown on the list, but only one value is available for selection in the Select Members screen. I have also checked the list to confirm that there are multiple values in that column, which there are.

Can anyone suggest how I can make PPS pick these values up please?

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 1):

There is a hotfix available that corrects this problem I believe.  Encountered the same issue (only the first dimension is available in Dashboard Designer).

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2589344?wa=wsignin1.0

The hotfix corrected the problem for me.

David

Answer (score 0):

Some time since I have used Dashboard Designer. But if I remember correctly Dashboard Designer will only pick up values that are used when you use a SharePoint-list as a datasource. If you only have tasks in your list with Status Completed, you can only pick Completed from the members screen. It doesn't matter how many choices the column has, only how many of the choices are used.